# NGINX rewrite http to https

Tags: nginx, redirect, f5

I am trying to rewrite HTTP to HTTPS. It is working properly in browser it is redirecting even if I access through private IP. But when I send request from another server it is returning ***HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently***.

My scenario:

- Client sends request to public IP (X.X.X.X:80) - F5 proxy
- X.X.X.X:80 proxy to my server Y.Y.Y.Y:80 (NGINX)
- On my server NGINX rewrites all http request to https.
- Finally, NGINX proxy pass to NodeJS and Java services.

Here is my NGINX config.

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     private-domain.company.local;
        return  301     https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen  443     ssl;
        server_name     private-domain.company.local;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/web.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/web.error.log;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/web.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/web.key;
        ssl_ciphers             EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location /{
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:8050/api/;
        }

}
```

When I try to curl from another server, it is returning 301.

```
curl -X POST http://X.X.X.X/api/url/to/send -v
```

The response:

```
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/url/to/send HTTP/1.1
> Host: X.X.X.X
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.1
< Date: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 07:42:45 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://private-domain.company.local/api/url/to/send
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host X.X.X.X left intact
```

I have tried few solutions on internet, but still no luck for me.

Comment: curl does not follow a redirect 301 by default (unlike a browser which will follow by default). What happens if you add `-L` as in `curl -L <URL>`?

Comment: @qrsngky Same result, but it is logging some failure about SSL verification.  ```curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate```. We have self signed certificate, does it affect HTTPS rewrites ?

Comment: How about further adding `-k` (to ignore invalid and self-signed certificate checks on curl)?

Comment: If you use a self-seigned certificate - all browsers will complain about it, unless you install the root CA that issued this certificate locally on the PC of each user. Therefore it is recommended to use at least LetsEncrypt if not some other globally trusted authority.